# MonoDevelop: IDE does not auto-format braces

Tags: c#, editor, monodevelop, code-formatting, brackets

I am trying to write C# code in MonoDevelop for Ubuntu Linux, but the editor will not format the braces. It used to format them nicely, like so:

```
void Method()
{
    if (condition)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Then one time as I reopened MonoDevelop, the editor started leaving the left brace hanging:

```
void Method() {
    //cursor left here after pressing Enter, no right brace
```

After I went to Edit > Preferences > Text Editor > Behavior > Checked "Insert matching brace", the editor started appending a } to the end of the block. However, the problem is that now my code is formatted Eclipse/Java-style, which I definitely don't want. See below:

```
void Method() {
    if (condition) {
        //...
    }
}
```

For some reason, going to Edit > Preferences > Source Code > Code Formatting > C# > Setting policy to "Microsoft Visual Studio" doesn't help with this. "Enable on the fly code formatting" is checked off, too. Edit > Format > Document works perfectly though, so I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Edit > Preferences > Source Code > Code Formatting are IDE settings which are used when creating new solutions/projects. You should go into your solution settings(double click on solution in SolutionPad) and change settings under "Source Code->Code Formatting->C# source code".

MonoDevelop supports per project(or solution if project has "inherit" policy set).

Comment: What version of MonoDevelop are you using?

Comment: That is so old.. I suggest you to install newer version from http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin